# How to add jenkins build result to project page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Image Gallery Plugin, here it displays the gallery in build page. But i want to add latest result(Gallery) to project home page, How can i do this?
I tried "getProjectAction" but this executes only when we do the configuration. I looked into "perform" method which is already exist in this plugin source, It has build.action to post the result. How the build.action works? Is it particularly adding action to only build or Can we even add it to project home?

Please help...

Comment: Still not get way to display on Job home page. waiting for your answers.